# spring webflux webclient response convert list of string to string

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, mono, spring-webflux

Response:

```
[ 
 {
  "version": "1.0",
  "content": [
    "12345",
    "67076",
    "123462",
    "604340",
    "1331999",
    "1332608",
    "1785581",
   ]
 }
]
```

Code:

```
Mono<List<String>> mp = webClient.get().uri(accountMgmtURI)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Map.class)
    .flatMap(trans-> {
       List<String> content= (List<String>) trans.get("content");
       System.out.println("content :: "+content);
       return Mono.just(content);
     }); 
System.out.println("content :: "+mp.toString()); 
String sites=mp.toString();
```

Comment: Mono<List<String> > mp= webClient.get().uri(accountMgmtURI)
                  .retrieve()
                         .bodyToMono(Map.class)
                         .flatMap(trans->{
List<String> content= (List<String>) trans.get("content");
 System.out.println("content :: "+content);
 return Mono.just(content);
                          });

System.out.println("content :: "+mp.toString());
   );

String sites=mp.toString();

Comment: Please post your expected output and explain the problem that you are facing

Comment: the response values are not coming in "sites"  , i want the response in pipe(|) separated format like  : sites:"12345|67076|776788........"... but i am not able to get any values in debug mode in also where i m doing wrong

Comment: You're trying to map to `bodyToMono(Map.class)`, but the response you got is an array of elements. I don't think you can properly map these to a `Mono<Map>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first issue is that the API you're using is not returning a single object, but an array of objects, indicated by the square brackets (`[]`).

This means you should at least refactor your code to use `bodyToFlux()` in stead of `bodyToMono()`:

```java
client
    .get()
    .retrieve()
    // bodyToFlux() in stead of bodyToMono(
    .bodyToFlux(Map.class)
    // ...
```

---

The second issue is that it isn't easy to work with a `Map` in this case since you would have to cast everything the whole time as you weren't able to pass any generics. Working with a proper class, would make things easier. For example, you could write the following class:

```java
public class VersionContent {
    private String version;
    private List<String> content;

    // TODO: Getters + Setters
}
```

And change your code to:

```java
client
    .get()
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(VersionContent.class)
    .map(VersionContent::getContent)
    .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
    // ...
```

This piece of code will retrieve the content for each object, and `flatMap` it so that each individual value is emitted separately.

---

Right now, each item within the `content` array would be published individually. This brings us to the third issue, which is that you're not concatenating your strings.

To concat items, you could use the `reduce()` operator:

```java
client
    .get()
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(VersionContent.class)
    .map(VersionContent::getContent)
    .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
    // reduce() can be used to merge all individual items to a single item
    .reduce((sites, site) -> sites + "|" + site)
    // ...
```

---

The final issue is that you're using `toString()`, which won't work. One of the key aspects of reactive programming is that everything happens **asynchronously**. That means that if you try to do anything with your data in the main thread, nothing will happen.

Additionally, another feature of publishers like `Mono` and `Flux` is that they're **lazy**. Without a proper subscription, nothing will even happen.

The solution is to properly `subscribe()` to get your value, for example:

```java
client
    .get()
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(VersionContent.class)
    .map(VersionContent::getContent)
    .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
    .reduce((sites, site) -> sites + "|" + site)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

For your example, the code above would print the following to the console:

```
12345|67076|123462|604390|1331999|1332608|1785581
```

Be aware, this also means that every operation you want to do with these sites, should be done asynchronously.

If you don't want to work asynchronously, you can use the `block()` operator like this:

```java
String sites = client
    .get()
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(VersionContent.class)
    .map(VersionContent::getContent)
    .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
    .reduce((sites, site) -> sites + "|" + site)
    .block();
```

Comment: Can you explain why we shouldn't use flux with webclient if we wanted to use block in the above example? I thought rest template was on the way out (ok years away), what would the alternative be?

Comment: @octo-carrot I'll keep using `RestTemplate`, but that's probably not a good alternative. I removed the paragraph mentioning it shouldn't be used for blocking calls.

Answer (score 3):

Please use ready solutions. You should not use `List<String> content= (List<String>) trans.get("content")`. Java is strong typing language - so create classes for types. And frameworks as spring works with classes and objects.

At this case:

```
public class VersionedDataResponse {
   private List<VersionedData> versionedDataList;
}
....
public class VersionedData {
    private String version;
    private List<String> content;
}
```

And spring will convert it at `bodyToMono(VersionedDataResponse.class)`